# How to assert two Class type ArrayList which contains class type elements?

Tags: java, junit, collections, assert

I have two List something like `List<A> listExpected` and `List<A> listActual`. I want to compare the elements of these lists but the problem is some elements of these lists are of Class type so my assertion `AssertEqual` is getting failed. Any idea how can i assert these two lists without manually asserting each elements one by one because there are more than 30 elements.Thanks.
Below is the example of the lists element I am getting

`Example`

```
List<A> listExpected =[elem1, elem2, Obj@33322, elem3];
List<A> listActual =[elem1, elem2, Obj@346762, elem3];
```

`Dummy Code`

```
Class CashWire {
    String name = "Name";
    String add = "Address";
    String a;
    String b;
    DeliveryInfo diInfo = new DeliveryInfo(name, add);
    public CashWire(String a, String b, diInfo) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.diInfo = diInfo;
    }
}

class DeliveryInfo {
    String name;
    String add;
    public DeliveryInfo(String name, String add) {
        this.name = name;
        this.add = add;
    }
}

class Main {
    public m1() {
        List <CashWire> list = (List<CashWire>) obj.getData() //will return object type data                                                                
    //    list =<[CashWire[a = "Some String", b = "Some String", 
    //                        diInfo = DeliveryInfo @7872348]]> 
    }
}
```

Comment: of course 100 is not equal to "100" since the first is considered as integer and the latter a String. Maybe it is better to write some real examples of your lists and their types. Do you have two lists of objects to compare or two lists of user-defined class ?

Comment: `Obj@346762` is not a Class instance.  It’s simply an object which does not define a toString override.  Perhaps it also neglected to override `public boolean equals(Object)`?

Comment: Two Array lists of user defined class. And in those ArrayList I have some String values and some Objects(Another user defined class object) and I want to assert these two lists.

Comment: @VGR actually its not. That `Obj@33322`  and `Obj@346762` is of class type which also has some fields. When I am just using `AssertEquals` on `listExpected ` and `listActual ` I am getting error just because both Objects inside the list are different.

Comment: If you just want to compare the Strings in your Lists, make copies of the lists and remove non-String elements from them.  For instance:  `Assert.assertEquals("Checking if lists are the same.", listExpected.stream().filter(o -> o instanceof String).collect(Collectors.toList()), listActual.stream().filter(o -> o instanceof String).collect(Collectors.toList()));`  (Personally, I would not use Streams;  I would create two new Lists and would call their `removeIf` methods, then pass them to assertEquals.)

Comment: I guess it should work. Will let you know how did it go. Thanks tho.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I got a solution which works fine for me

Mockito offers a reflection-matcher:

`For latest version of Mockito use:`

```
Assert.assertTrue(new ReflectionEquals(expected, excludeFields).matches(actual));
```

`For older versions use:`

```
Assert.assertThat(actual, new ReflectionEquals(expected, excludeFields));
```